# Is there a way to uniquely advertise the same app on the App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an iOS application that I wish to market to different cities in Canada. Ideally in terms of marketing potential my best bet would be to split it into separate projects that way for example I can advertise "Toronto AppName" local to the area instead of just "AppName" (if I were to have one app and let the user select their city when they enter the application). Local media sources are more inclined to give publicity if the app is unique to their city. So if I have "Toronto AppName" I am more likely to get publicity as opposed to if I go to them trying to promote the app "AppName" because they will not think it is as unique to their city. The functionality is the exact same for all cities. The differences are minor (map difference, different information loaded), so I am almost certain Apple wouldn't let me create 100 different applications because of this.

Is there a way to advertise to a city on the app store while having only one application? Ideally I would want the user to be able to download an app with their city's name in the app name but i'm guessing that is not possible if I have only one version of the app? What can I do if I want to keep the city's name in the application but am almost certain Apple won't let me have 100 different apps for each city?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to answer with two letters but stackoverflow wouldn't let me. Anyway, no.